# Requiring pickadate.js with Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, browserify-shim, pickadate

I would like to use the responsive **pickadate.js** date picker in my Backbone.js application.

I am using Browserify to manage modules and dependencies and wondering how to integrate pickadate.

I started with a `npm install pickadate` which added the node module to my project.

Then, in one of my views, I try this:

```
var pickadate = require('pickadate');
this.$el.find('input[name=dateEntry]').pickadate();
```

The error is on the second line which throws this error:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.$el.find('input[name=dateEntry]').pickadate()') (app.js, line 16654)
```

I think I should use browserify-shim but.... how? Pickadate does not export anything.

**UPDATE**

Using debowerify with grunt (works for other modules):

```
var pickadate = require('pickadate');

//... 

render: function() {

//...

this.$el.find('.form-group input[name=dateEntry]').pickadate();
}
```

[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.$el.find('.form-group input[name=dateEntry]').pickadate()') (app.js, line 18803)

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with browserify, but more to do with scope confusion. Hard to tell as you've barely shared anything about the function where this code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the steps below successfully:

Using debowerify with browserify, I can do like below:

```
require('jquery');
require('pickadate');
```

Comment: I'll try, thank you. So you downloaded pickadate using Bower?

Comment: In this case, I will try to use bower to download pickdate first

Comment: Have you try require('pickdate') instead of var pickadate = require('pickadate'); ?

Comment: Do you mean not assigning it to a variable? Yes, obviously. And... the module name is 'pickadate', NOT 'pickdate'.

Comment: @FabioB. take note that the sequence is important require('jquery') follow by require('pickadate')

Comment: Finally, I made a bundle with picker.js + picker.date.js and required it. That worked for me.