# What's the right way to make pickadate play well with browserify?

Tags: browserify, pickadate

I've been struggling and very frustrated because I can't find a way to make pickadate play well with browserify. I'm migrating a Backbone app from AMD but pickadate seems impossible to work with it. I must say that I began to use browserify recently so I'm not an expert but I could migrate the rest of my code without any major incident. Of course I'm open to receive some tips and references to master browserify :)

I have jquery and pickadate installed via npm and when trying to use pickadate I'm getting the classic error: 

`undefined is not a function`

I used this way of requiring (note the use without assigning the require to a variable):

`require("jquery");
require("pickadate");`

I saw this on an answer here at stackoverflow ([Requiring pickadate.js with Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888292/requiring-pickadate-js-with-browserify)) but it doesn't work in my case.

Any help or reference about where to find help will be pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of pickadate as a module only exposes the instance of PickerConstructor but it doesn't expose DatePicker neither TimePicker so every time we try to instantiate a date picker or time picker we got the error `undefined is not a function` because neither of them have been loaded and so no `jquery.extend` invocation have been made to append them to the jQuery object.

What is needed is some kind of facade / wrapper to expose all the pickadate functionality out of the box.

For this I made some small changes directly to the pickadate code base. I added an `index.js` that works as the facade / wrapper for `picker.js`, `pick.date` and `pick.time`, allowing them to be used out of the box with Browserify by issuing the typical `require('pickadate')`. It doesn't need to be assigned to a variable since pickadate attaches itself directly to the jQuery object. You can check [this gist with the `index.js` code I used](https://gist.github.com/mogarick/edfe96cb0a7682996c1d)

This change is a copy of the way the CryptoJS library by @evanvosberg exposes its different algorithms through the same pattern implemented in its `index.js` file.

The only additional change would be to modify the property `main` in pickadate `package.json` to point to `index.js`.

I've just send a message to @amsul, the [pickadate](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js) author asking for the possibility of integrate this changes directly into the pickadate github repo.

I hope people trying to use pickadate with browserify can find this solution and stop getting frustrated trying to make them play well together!

Greetings to everybody!